# How to configure this to be rendered in a UITableView or should this be done in multiple UITableView's

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I don't use UITableViews that much but need to in this case. I have a fairly complex Menu object. It has headers and items, like so (imagine a rails acts_as_tree where the menuHeaders array can be arbitrarily deep so there three abstractions: a Menu, a MenuHeaders array which can be nested, and a MenuItems array):

```
Menu
 \menuHeaders is an array
    menuHeader - name="Service"
      \menuHeaders[]
      \menuItems
        \menuItem="transmission fix"
        \menuItem="replace gaskets"
    menuHeader - name="Specials"
      \menuHeaders
          \menuHeader -name="Tires"
             \menuItem - special tire
             \menuItem - verySpecial Tire
      \menuItems
          \menuItem - name="oil change"
          \menuItem - name="windows clean"
```

Output in table:

```
Service
 transmission fix
 replace gaskets
Specials
  Tires
    special tire
    verySpecial Tire
  oil change
  windows clean
```

I am not sure if I should structure this into a single UITableView or whether each sub-array should be its own UITableView or how I would iterate over each element? It seems like the cellForRowAtIndexPath can only handle either single arrays or 2D arrays which is not what this is. How would I structure this?

When I render in jQuery I do something like

```
renderMenHeader(menuHeader)
  if(menuHeader.menuItems){
    for(mi in menuHeader.menuItems){
      renderMenuItem(mi)
    }
  }

  if(menuHeader.menuHeaders){
    for(mh in menuHeader.menuHeaders){
      renderMenuHeader(mh)
    }
  }
```

but I am not sure how to map this to UITableView abstraction. In all honest, I would rather just keep these as separate UIView's but they get up to 300-500 units so I need the ability to handle processing of only visible elements. If there is a workaround for handling this in generic UIView's that would also be of interest.

Comment: All you need to do is to add a new method to the "fairly complex Menu object" that will return an item based on its index, from there you can manage offset and any other style elements as you like. Stacking scroll views in general and particularly table views doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: I agree that stacking scroll views or table views isn't a good idea. But I'm a bit lost as to how to actually implement this. the menuHeaders and menuItems exist as arrays but confused as to how to stucture this...

Comment: Fast (to implement, not to execute) and dirty (no cache): recursion. If you know that the elements are not going to be frequently changed it will be easier to create one plane array referencing all elements of the plane tree.

Comment: I really don't want to have to do some data transformation... ughh... but thinking something like you mention is the only way where we create a separate list and each item has characteristics of a menuHeader or a menuItem. Like a flatten of the whole thing